# How can I bypass bot blocking at Instagram to get the full page with file_get_contents()

Tags: instagram, file-get-contents

I am trying to scrape data from Instagram (IG) user page to use as stream feed at a website, but apparently IG uses a bot blocker so the PHP method does not return all the elements of the JSON string.

The data I am trying to fetch is the following, specifically the **`"ProfilePage":[{}]`** object which is visible via local browser **when not logged into IG**.

```
<script type="text/javascript">window._sharedData = {
"config": {
    "csrf_token": "MaYaasysNl6fy19YthOGUNVOXvYitbmO",
    "viewer": null,
    "viewerId": null
},
"country_code": "US",
"language_code": "en",
"locale": "en_US",
"entry_data": {
    "ProfilePage": [{
        "logging_page_id": "profilePage_28995773",
        "show_suggested_profiles": true,
        "show_follow_dialog": false,
        "graphql": {
            "user": {
//[...more data follows including images and links]
}
}
</script>
```

But what I get when scraped via php script is the following which does not include the `ProfilePage` element and data within the `entry_data` object.

```
<script type="text/javascript">window._sharedData = {
"config": {
    "csrf_token": "VgzhYPHc6dXWP3qQFKjlWYEBK59bDo6A",
    "viewer": null,
    "viewerId": null
},
"country_code": "US",
"language_code": "en",
"locale": "en_US",
"entry_data": {
    "LoginAndSignupPage": [{
        "captcha": {
            "enabled": false,
            "key": ""
        },
        "gdpr_required": false,
        "tos_version": "row",
        "username_hint": ""
    }]
},
"hostname": "www.instagram.com",
"is_whitelisted_crawl_bot": false,
"connection_quality_rating": "EXCELLENT",
"deployment_stage": "c2",
"platform": "web",
"nonce": "kQ3AWksy1DQ9TXuwLdKMkw==",
"mid_pct": 84.93332,
"zero_data": {},
"cache_schema_version": 3,
"server_checks": {},
</script>
```

I have tried using `cURL`, `file_get_contents()`, `new DOMDocument()->loadHTMLFile()` to get all the page source, then `preg_match` for the line needed, but neither method could bypass the blocker.

```
$ig = file_get_contents($url);
preg_match_all('#shortcode":"(.*)",#i',$ig, $match);
```

#### Expected return

```
Array
(
    [0] => CB-W_D2h3Sz
    [1] => B65TtGYBH8Z
    [2] => B65SNqsha6O
    [3] => B62NvlShguS
    [4] => B6zwW5CBETr
    [5] => B6wbz5nB_dP
    [6] => B6wa3rxBOOP
    [7] => B6uw9RwBSSd
    [8] => B6tg9dIh_XB
    [9] => B6tYekYhIe8
    [10] => B6pR-pGhvoE
    [11] => B6pRhVgBwaZ
)
```

#### Literal return

```
Array
(
)
```

#### How can I get the desired data?

Answer (score 1):

I defined a solution

```
https://instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_id=17888483320059182&variables={"id":"217723373","first":8,"after":null}
```

Comment: How do you ge the user id from a username? The ig basic profile api, returns a user id that is different and doesn't work with this graphql api.